# Spark 2: ArrayStoreException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a `Dataset` of a `Event case class`:

```
val ds: Dataset[Event] = df.as[Event]
```

I can do some operations on it like `count` (`println(ds.count())`).

But when I try to print it (I know that I can use `ds.show()`) as follows:

```
ds.take(10).foreach(e =>  println(e))
```

I get an `Execution Exception: ArrayStoreException: application.Event`.

What is wrong with this line of code?

Comment: Could you please provide the code of the Event class and the version of Spark you're running?